# How to find the parameters for a skewed normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution, predictive-models, density-function, skew-normal-distribution

According to this website: https://datayze.com/labor-probability-calculator

One can model the probability distribution function of spontaneous labour given two pieces of information.

a) the due date of the pregnant women
b) the current date

I have a set of information that provides the due date of labour, and actual date of labour for hundred's of women. It looks like this:

| Est. Due Date | Actual Labour Date |
| --- | --- |
| 11th Sep | 9th Sep |
| 12th Oct | 18th Oct |
| ... | ... |
| 15th Aug | 26th July |

I would like to be able to generate a model similar to the above linked website that allows me to make predictions similar to the website. I.e. I can make a statement like

> Your due date is 14th November 2022, given you haven't already given
> birth there is a x% chance you will give birth today.

or more generally a function that takes a due date as input and outputs the probability of the labour happening over the next number of days (until that probability hits 0 or close enough)

I.e. if the due date is 14th Nov and labour hasn't occurred yet it might produce:

| Date | Probability of labour |
| --- | --- |
| 11th Nov | 3.1% |
| 12th Nov | 3.6% |
| ... | ... |
| 15th Dec | 0.00003% |

The website suggests a skewed normal distribution, but I am not sure how to generate these given the data I have.

Does anyone know how to model such a distribution given what I have and how to use that to make predictions?

Answer (score 1):

1. I disagree with the website author that, based on the information given, these data necessarily follow a skewed normal distribution. I agree the data most likely exhibit skewness (non-equal median and *mean* - for some reason the author discusses the *mode* on this point, perhaps a Freudian slip?), and a skewed normal may provide a reasonable approximation. What would be most useful is a continuous histogram of the data based on a kernal density estimator, and based day-by-day labor probabilities on that.
2. Whereas you often see univariate statistics such as the mean and standard deviation being reported on key variables in a dataset, this does not imply that the data are normal, nor are these measures invalidated when the data do not follow normal rules. As a method of moment estimator, the mean and SD are a robust measure of location and scale.
3. Estimation of a skewed normal distribution is discussed widely. The wikipedia article, even, gives a nice overview. Typically, you identify the power law that optimally transforms the data by a Box-Cox transformation, and after applying the inverse transform, estimating the mean and standard deviation to identify the 3 parameter normal curve.

Comment: Okay thank you for the reply. In light of what you have said do you think there is a better way to achieve what I am asking then? Do you have any suggestions?